# Reading INI file using Boost Property Tree when ini file not exist

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost

I'm using `Boost.PropertyTree` to load INI file:

```
read_ini( INI_FILE_NAME, pt );
```

If ini file not exist then `Boost` raises exception.

How to read `ini` file without rising exception, but getting info that it not exist?

Comment: Did you consider catching the exception?

Comment: I hope that boost has more elegant solution

Comment: Exception is also useful in case you have the file but you open the wrong one. i.e. You open a jpg image instead, or file formatting has some error, like missing closing tags. These, like missing files, does not allows to read informations, so exception is thrown for same consequence (no informations).

Comment: If you call exceptions not elegant, you may consider using a different language. Exceptions are a core mechanism of C++, and yes it is elegant.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You have to handle all exceptions and choose which you want to work with / display.

```
try
{
     read_ini( INI_FILE_NAME, pt );
}
catch( std::exception &ex )
{
    // you either print it out or have a MessageBox pop up or hide it.
    std::cerr << ex.what( ) << std::endl;
}
```

Just handle the exception accordingly.

Comment: this throws exception if parsing fails, not only when file does not exist, and it does not address the question *"How to read ini file without rising exception"*

Comment: @PiotrS. this catches all exceptions what you do with what exception is up to you so it answers the question. It will always raise an exception or at least a boost error code which it should.

Comment: this catches all exceptions derived from `std::exception` to be precise. and don't assume OP can use exceptions if he asks how to solve the problem without exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Structure your code as below to handle the exception correctly

```
try
{
    read_ini(INI_FILE_NAME, pt);

    //Do something with pt
}
catch(ptree_bad_data& ex)
{
    // Log or error string stating that the data read is corrupt
}
catch(ptree_bad_path& ex)
{
    // Log or error string stating that there was problem in 
    // accessing the INI at the given location.
}
catch(ptree_error& ex)
{
    // Log or error string stating generic ptree exception.
}
catch(...)
{
    // Log or error string stating a generic exception.
    // Might want to rethrow the exception to address it correctly.

    //throw;
}
```

.
.
.

This will handle your exception, avoid an attempt to use the unpopulated `pt` and tell you the exact problem that occurred in the process, while allowing your code to continue without aborting.